# Graphql / Gatsby trying to filter by relative directory

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to sort images by their parent directory for separate galleries. My directory looks like /images/gallery-one. I think I'm close, but for whatever reason I can't get it to filter by relativePath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just sending me in the right direction.

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import Img from 'gatsby-image'


const ImageGallery = () => {


const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
query {
  images: allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images" }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        relativePath
        childImageSharp {
          id
          fluid {
            originalImg
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`)

const galleryImages = data.images.edges.node.filter(img => {
 

})

console.log(data)


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Gallery One</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default ImageGallery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. Using your GraphQL query and the following filter statement you get the `gallery-one` images like this:

```
    data.images.edges.filter(edge =>
      edge.node.relativePath.startsWith("gallery-one")
    )
```

(Keep in mind that `edges` is a list where each item contains a `node` and that `relativePath` will be e.g. `gallery-one/b.png`)

Here's my image directory structure:

[image: image directory structure]

Comment: My directory is set up exactly like this, but it's returning an empty array even though I have 5 images in the "gallery-one" folder.

Comment: Opps, my bad. Had an extra set of curly braces. Thanks!